# Huge White Space on Right Side of Website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, frameworks

I have a [Genesis Child Theme](http://granitefresno.com/) that's behaving very strange. The layout looks correct, but there's a huge blank white space on the right side and a scroll bar at the bottom. I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing the white space. There isn't a single div sticking out into that white space when I inspect with developer tools, and I can't find anything in the css that would be causing that issue.

The basic structure of the site is

```
<body>

  <site-container>

    <header>
    </header>

    <site-inner>
    </site-inner>

    <footer>
    </footer>  

  <site-container>

</body>
```

There are additional divs within the above structure, but there are tons of them and I'm not sure listing each one is valuable since the site itself will need to be inspected. I can't possibly list the entire code structure since it's a genesis based wordpress site.

Does anyone have a clue what might be causing the whitespace? I encountered this problem once before with a genesis child theme, but it turned out to be an image that wasn't resizing and it was easy to find the issue. This time I can't find it for the life of me.

[Here's the site link again.](http://granitefresno.com/)

Comment: Not without seeing the code/the website, but I might sound like you have a width set fairly wide.

Comment: Or an open /div. Or a margin-right set to a high neg number. Or if the  slideshow is full width, it may be set to a really large width without and overflow:hidden....it could be so many things..let's look at that site

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot to link the site! It's linked now in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by some CSS on your search input, around line 1456. Remove the `width: 100%`:

```
#search-3 input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What the? Why was that causing white space next to the actual site as wide as the site itself? Shouldn't width: 100%; contain it to the max size of the parent div? The parent div has a max-width defined.

Comment: Maybe it had something to do with the absolute positioned input button next to it? I discovered that was outside the regular flow and on the right side. Either way, it's looking like it should now. Thank so much for your help!

Comment: Glad that helped. From what I can see, there aren't many widths set up the chain, so the first thing it has to base its width on is pretty wide. Anyhow, it might be better to just move it way off screen with a negative left setting, rather than use clip to hide it, but it's up to you. :-)